# How to run r script on remote GPU?

Tags: r, remote-access

I am trying to run r script on a GPU server provided by the institute.
Specifications of GPU server are as follows:

```
Host Name: gpu01.cc.iitk.ac.in,  
Configuration: Four Tesla T10 GPUs added to each machine with 8 cores in each
Operating System: Linux  
Specific Usage: Parallel Programming under Linux using CUDA with C Language
```

R code:

```
setwd("~/Documents/tm dataset")
library(ssh)
session <- ssh_connect("dgaurav@gpu01.cc.iitk.ac.in")
print(session)
out <- ssh_exec_wait(session, command = 'articles1_test.R')
```

Error:

```
ksh: articles1_test.R: not found
```

Comment: What's your exact question? Error message is self-explanatory (*specified file doesn't exist*). Why you just don't login to the server and run R from there (ie, use the usual way).

Comment: Is the file correctly written with a shebang so that the shell knows how to run it? Can you ssh in manually and run `articles1_test.R` directly, or do you need an absolute or relative path, e.g., `/path/to/articles1_test.R`?

Answer (score 0):

Your dataset and script are only on local machine... you nneed to cooy the to remote server before you can run them.